# How can an element disapare during xslt even if I never specify "Remove" as action?

Tags: c#, xslt, msbuild, transformation

I have a very strange behaviour with my xslt transformation in one of our web-services.

We have the following section in the web.config file (with other things as well)

```
<AppSettings>
  <add key="TemporaryUpload.Folder" value="TempUpload\"/>
  <add key="MailClient.SmtpHost" value="" />
  <add key="MailClient.MailEnabled" value="false"/>
</AppSettings>
```

We then have a web.production.config transformation file which is triggered (can be seen on the transformed web.config for other parts). However we have a problem where one of the rows in the AppSettings section instead of being replaced is removed.

The transformation part looks like the follwing

```
<AppSettings>
  <add xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" key="MailClient.MailEnabled" value="true" />
  <add xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" key="MailClient.SmtpHost" value="mailhost.test.se"/>  
</AppSettings>
```

The first line is replaced accordinly but the second seems to somehow remove the element instead of replacing it. In other words the section in the transformed web.config is like the following

```
<AppSettings>
  <add key="TemporaryUpload.Folder" value="TempUpload\"/>
  <add key="MailClient.MailEnabled" value="true"/>
</AppSettings>
```

I have tried to using xdt:Transform="Replace" instead of "SetAttributes" but the effect seem to be the same.

As I have said all the rest of the transformations works as intended its just that single row that for some reason gets deleted instead of transformed.

So if anyone has any clues feel free to enlighten me, as it is at the moment I have to resort of checking the config file and inserting the row if it is missing but I'm worried that there might be other rows missing in the future.

Comment: Have you tried setting <add key="MailClient.SmtpHost" value="" /> to an actual value in your original we.config (eg <add key="MailClient.SmtpHost" value="dummy smtphost" />

Comment: There is an error in your XSLT. Without seeing your XSLT, we cannot help you find it.

Comment: Michael Kay, how can there be an error in my xslt when everything else except just that row works as intended? Anyway I will add more of the xslt so that you can look at it.

Angus Connell, No not really since I felt that an empty string is still a value but I'll try that.

Comment: For some reason it seems that replacing an empty string with a dummy value actually changed the behaviour of the transformation. Not sure if this was the cause but it worked so we are making this change.

Comment: Voting to close this question. For future questions: you have to post an _entire_, working stylesheet - then people can give sensible answers.

Comment: Well since everything else in the transformation stylesheet and web.config worked I didn't see the point in removing sensitive business information just to be able to post a more complete xslt. The problem was with just one single row whereas all the rest in  the file worked as intended. Most times in the questions in here an incomplete part of code is presented. The reason is that most code is not just something produced at home but at an customer and the code can be more or less sensitive... I close the question with a short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems have originated by the fact that the default value in the web.config was an empty row. As soon as I replaced the default value with a dummy value instead it all worked as intended.

I can't understand why this would be a fact for different behaviour but apparently it is. So the solution to this problem is NEVER set a default value in a web.config that will be transformed for different build definition to an empty string, always set a dummy value instead.